# Is there any way to reload previous ViewState of the page controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I can't find an answer about mine subject question. I tried to reload my ViewState of controls when the user go back to previous page.

First of all I want to save my ViewState to a Session variable and then when user want to go back to this page I want to reload it in PageLoad. But when I tried to save it, it always shown me that is nothing saved(null). So it is nothing to reload.

I tried to used `SaveViewState()` and `LoadViewState()` methods.

Here is a example code what have I tried:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["savedViewState"] != null && SaveViewState() != null)
            {
                Object saved = (Object)Session["savedViewState"];
                LoadViewState(saved);
            }
            else
            {
                Session["savedViewState"] = SaveViewState();
            }            
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you want to do actually ?  why do you need to save viewstate in session ?

Comment: When user want back to previous page he want to have the same filters.

Comment: Create a class and save the filter in its object and then save it to a session variable. 
For more refer here https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MovingViewStateToTheSessionObjectAndMoreWrongheadedness.aspx